# Compiling Wasm module with optimisation level 02 and 03 for loading in an AudioWorlet?

Tags: web-audio-api, emscripten, wasm-bindgen, audio-worklet

I’m trying to compile a .wasmmodule.js with additional optimisation for running in an AudioWorklet.

I use a .post.js file for appending 'export default Module' to the compiled Wasm, using the --post-js compilation flag. This works well with 01 optimisation, which is the current compilation configuration used in the worklet design pattern examples.

```
$(EMSCR) $(CFLAGS) --post-js $(POST_JS) -o $(OUTPUT) $(SRC_EM) $(SRC) 

CFLAGS=--bind -O1\
-s WASM=1 \
-s BINARYEN_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 \
-s SINGLE_FILE=1 \
-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
-s ABORTING_MALLOC=0 \
-s TOTAL_MEMORY=128Mb
```

I’m getting compilation issues with the optimisation flags 02 and 03 because I need to load Wasm with a default export.

If I comment that --post.js export, the compilation runs fine with 02 or 03 optimisation level. However, then we can't load the Wasm into the worklet, with exceptions:

*E.g. "Error on loading worklet:  SyntaxError: The requested module '../../build/m.wasmmodule.js' does not provide an export named 'default*

I tried different combinations but I wasn't able to overcome this.

Any ideas if there is any different configuration I might try?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ESM JavaScript syntax `import MyModule from './MyModule.js'`, try using these Emscripten flags:

```
-s EXPORT_ES6=1 \
-s MODULARIZE=1 \
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by using `--extern-post-js` instead of `--post-js`, which appends the export **after** all other compiler work has been done, including optimization.